# Error: shiny-server - Error loading config: Unknown directive

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am running `Shiny Server v1.5.3.838` on the Ubuntu 16.04.2 server. Earlier, I had an issue with the shiny server port 3838. So, I tried to modified it in `shiny-server.conf` file. But after modification, I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: Unknown directive "" (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:1:1)
```

I undo changes in the `shiny-server.conf` file. But, it is the same error I am getting.

This is my shiny-server.log file says:

```
[2017-07-12 00:29:03.433] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.3.838 (Node.js v6.10.0)
[2017-07-12 00:29:03.439] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2017-07-12 00:29:03.516] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: Unknown directive "" (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:1:1)
[2017-07-12 00:29:03.517] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

following is my `shiny-server.conf` file includes:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

And `sudo systemctl status shiny-server` returns, as following:

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2017-07-12 11:31:22 UTC; 16min ago
Process: 7290 ExecStopPost=/bin/sleep 5 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 7276 ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 7275 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /opt/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server --pidfile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid >> /var/log/shiny-server.log 2>&1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 7275 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 12 11:31:14 san1-droplet systemd[1]: Starting ShinyServer...
Jul 12 11:31:22 san1-droplet systemd[1]: Started ShinyServer.
```

I have tried several things but no clue how to fix this and start a shiny server.

Comment: hmm, are u using `nginx` or `apache2` as well? Try disabling those as the `shiny-server.conf` looks ok to me

Comment: Yes, I am using nginx. I will disable it and let you know.

Comment: @PorkChop I disable the nginx using `sudo service nginx stop`. The same problem persists. I added the status of shiny-server in the question. I hope it gives more information about the error I am facing.

Comment: It looks as if shiny Server is interpreting an empty line (or a comment line) as a directive. Did you try to remove the comments and empty lines already? I'd start with the first one. And I am aware that this shouldn't be a problem, but it wouldn't be the first time an empty line in a config file wrecks havoc. Or it might be a wrongly interpreted EOF or so as well, given that the problem only occured after you edited it.

Comment: check for an extra space.